# Query for getting posts with their custom fields data in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Suppose I have two categories A and B. Now I have uploaded some Posts A1, A2 under Category A and B1, B2 under Category B. Also for every Posts I have added some new custom fields using ACF plugin like thumbnail_image, first_image,second_image,third_image.

I have added image for better understand below.

[image]

So if I want to retrieve all the Posts of Category A with their custom fields what is the Query.

Anybody help please ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/), you can call all the posts of a specific category using the query below. This is the minimal example. The `'cat'` argument must be the category ID. You can discover what is the ID in the url when editing the category.

```php
<?php $query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'cat'            => 5
  )); ?>
```

Then, inside the loop, you will need the post ID that you get using `get_the_ID();`.
Finally, to get the field image, you use `get_field()`. The first parameter is the name of the field and the second parameter is the post ID.

```php
<?php while($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>

  <?php $postID = get_the_ID(); // current post ID ?>

  <img src="<?php echo get_field("thumbnail_image", $postID); ?>" alt="">
  <img src="<?php echo get_field("first_image", $postID); ?>" alt="">
  <img src="<?php echo get_field("second_image", $postID); ?>" alt="">
  <img src="<?php echo get_field("third_image", $postID); ?>" alt="">

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Don't forget to specify the format of the returned data as URL (string) when creating them in the ACF.